# Port BinaryReader to IEnumerator?

Tags: c#, .net, binary, ienumerable, binaryreader

I have a method that reads a variable number of bytes from an `IEnumerable<byte>`, and stops when it finds a certain flag.

Is there an easy and efficient way to adapt a `BinaryReader` and make the method read only the necessary amount of bytes?

P.S. It could also be a `StreamReader` of another type if there is no choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you need to pass a `BinaryReader` to the method that expects `IEnumerable<byte>`. If so, try to use this class:

```
public class MyBinaryReader : BinaryReader, IEnumerable<byte>
{
    public MyBinaryReader(Stream input)
        : base(input)
    {
    }

    public MyBinaryReader(Stream input, Encoding encoding)
        : base(input, encoding)
    {
    }

    public IEnumerator<byte> GetEnumerator()
    {
        while (BaseStream.Position < BaseStream.Length)
            yield return ReadByte();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
private static void ReadFew(IEnumerable<byte> list)
{
    var iter = list.GetEnumerator();
    while (iter.MoveNext() && iter.Current != 3)
    {
    }
}

using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(new byte[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }))
using (MyBinaryReader reader = new MyBinaryReader(memStream))
{
    ReadFew(reader);
    Console.WriteLine("Reader stopped at position: " + memStream.Position);
}
```

Output:

> Reader stopped at position: 4

Comment: I wish there was a shorter solution I don't want to pollute the code base with with redundant classes. I think I'm gonna use ex. methods with a local private class instead. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @Dmitry Your implementation of MyBinaryReader doesn´t compile. Why ? It seems all is right. I have typed the missing using's also.

Comment: @Dmitry The error was "cannot implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()' because it does not have the matching return type of 'System.Collections.IEnumerator". And my fault was not declaring parent namespace System.Collections. Thanks